# How can I convert output buffer of MediaCodec into OpenCV Mat?

Tags: android, opencv, media, android-mediacodec

I'm developing an app which reads video file and play while processing each frame (such as color converting). Since I'm newbie of Android and media processing, I can't configure how can I do this.

Currently, I'm trying to retrieve frames (image) using MediaCodec API, and process each frame using OpenCV.
But, I'm stuck in converting output buffer (ByteBuffer) into OpenCV mat.

How can I do this? Or, if you guys know better way to make a this type of app, please give me advice. Even a small piece of advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you won't find many people who know both libraries. you need to show what you want us to work with. [mre]

Comment: opencv can convert some planar formats into its native "BGR888" format. you just need to figure out how to create a `cv::Mat` from your java byte buffer

Answer (score 0):

Images (video frames) that the `MediaCodec` outputs are typically represented as buffers of planar or semi-planar `YCbCr` (often referred to as YUV) data.

AFAIK OpenCV does not support these formats directly. So you need to convert the data into another format (e.g. RGBA or grayscale). You can look at the implementation of [JavaCamera2Frame](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/android-21/java/org/opencv/android/JavaCamera2View.java) as a starting point (it assumes a camera image format).

Note, that you need to check the actual [format](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image#getFormat()) of the image (e.g. `YUV_420_888`, `YUV_422_888`, `YUV_444_888`) and apply the appropriate color conversion.

An alternative approach is to use a [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture) and OpenGL ES to do the conversion on the GPU and then read it back as RGBA data. But this requires writing some amount of setup code.